# How to find specific video html tag using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know how to use beautifulsoup in python.

I have this search engine with a list of different urls.

I want to get only the html tag containing a video embed url. and get the link.

example

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = '''https://archive.org/details/20070519_detroit2'''
    #or this.. html = '''http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/'''
    #or this... html = '''https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI3zBtE_S_k'''

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

what should I do next . to get the html tag of video, or object or the exact link of the video..

I need it to put it on my iframe. i will integrate the python to my php. so getting the link of the video and outputting it using the python then i will echo it on my iframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the html of the page not just the url

use the built-in lib `urllib` like this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = '''https://archive.org/details/20070519_detroit2'''
#open and read page
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
#create BeautifulSoup parse-able "soup"
soup = BS(html)
#get the src attribute from the video tag
video = soup.find("video").get("src")
```

also with the site you are using i noticed that to get the embed link just change `details` in the link to `embed` so it looks like this:

```
https://archive.org/embed/20070519_detroit2
```

so if you want to do it to multiple urls without having to parse just do something like this:

```
url = '''https://archive.org/details/20070519_detroit2'''
spl = url.split('/')
spl[3] = 'embed'
embed = "/".join(spl)
print embed
```

---

**EDIT**

to get the embed link for the other links you provided in your edit you need to look through the html of the page you are parsing, look until you fint the link then get the tag its in then the attribute

for

```
'''http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/'''
```

just do

```
soup.find("iframe").get("src")
```

the `iframe` becuase the link is in the iframe tag and the `.get("src")` because the link is the src attribute

You can try the next one because you should learn how to do it if you want to be able to do it in the future :)

Good luck!

Comment: I got there first, chris! XD

Comment: @ChristianCareaga  ow yes. i kinda get the url part of the archive.org.. can i ask for another help. i update my question.. i think i will a different kinds of algorithm because i will have a different indexing of urls. thank you in advance. :)

Comment: @ChristianCareaga thanks with this. i will try this now. I maybe ask you again in the near future. Sorry, I'm a new programmer hehehe.

Comment: @Vincent I know how you feel! when i learned BeautifulSoup it was *very* confusing but so helpful once you get it !

Comment: @ChristianCareaga thanks for this. you've answered my question. :)

Comment: @Vincent No problem! good luck with your learning and project!:)

Comment: @ChristianCareaga how about <object> tag and the attribute is "data=" . i got an error on that. i just change the video to object and the src to data . it's not working. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42476/discussion-between-vincent-and-christian-careaga)

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse a URL. BeautifulSoup is used to parse an *html page*. Retrieve the page first:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.ulropen("https://archive.org/details/20070519_detroit2")

html = data.read()
```

Then you can use `find`, and then take the `src` attribute:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
video = soup.find('video')
src = video['src']
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a one liner to get all the downloadable MP4 file in that page, in case you need it.

```
import bs4, urllib2
url = 'https://archive.org/details/20070519_detroit2'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and '.mp4' in tag['href'])]
print links
```

Here are the output:

```
['/download/20070519_detroit2/20070519_detroit_jungleearth.mp4',
'/download/20070519_detroit2/20070519_detroit_sweetkissofdeath.mp4', 
'/download/20070519_detroit2/20070519_detroit_goodman.mp4',
...
'/download/20070519_detroit2/20070519_detroit_wilson_512kb.mp4']
```

These are relative links and you and put them together with the domain and you get absolute path.

Comment: thanks for this. i got another idea. but how about the video that is playing. as you see on  the link that i've included.

Comment: @Vincent The video that is playing is cellout, right? it is in the list and I just cannot put all the output in this post but it is in the list.

Comment: oh Im sorry. i just tried it and i was about to reply to you. sorry my fault.. hehe

Comment: @B.Mr.W. in your one liner above which works great how would you add .mkv to that so  it does both mp4 and mkv