# how to find the video tag in html5 using bs4 (python)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In the code below I created a function that tries to get the src from a
video tag in html5 using bs4, but it doesn't seems to work

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(start_at, end):  
i = 39841

while (i + start_at) <= (end + i):
    url = "http://wwww.getvids.org/watch/" + str(i + start_at)
    meet = requests.get(url).text
    bso4 = BeautifulSoup(meet, "html.parser")

    for vidL in bso4.findAll("video", {'class': 'vjs-tech'}):
        print vidL.get("src")

        print 'done'
    start_at += 1
```

**for the record i saw this "[How to find specific video html tag using beautiful soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365189/how-to-find-specific-video-html-tag-using-beautiful-soup)" but i could not get it to work**

Comment: I believe you should be using `find_all` instead of `findAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ("**find_all**" instead of "*findAll*"):

```
for vidL in bso4.find_all("video", {'class': 'vjs-tech'}):
```

Misstyping BS4's "find_all" is one of the most common errors with this library.